# Update Excel Sheet Using SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm attempting to write a procedure that would use an ADODB connection to update records (rows) in a closed workbook.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to reference multiple tables (worksheets) and multiple fields (columns) in Excel...

My SQL statement looks like this:

```
SQLstr = "UPDATE [Location$] " & vbNewLine & _
        "SET [Location$].[City]=[Current Location$].[City] " & vbNewLine & _
        "WHERE [Location$].[Name]=[Current Location$].[Name]"

cn.Execute SQLstr
```

This statement's goal is to update the City field on the Location sheet using the City field on the Current Location sheet (in the same workbook).

The problem is that when I try to execute the above statement, I get a run-time error:

*-2147217904: No value given for one or more required parameters.*

It seems like this should be simple, but I'm missing something, and I haven't been able to find any good documentation on how to handle multiple sheets/fields/workbooks in SQL.

Also, I'm not very skilled with SQL already, so my SQL syntax could be wrong too...but I'm not sure.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case we missed something on the connection string or other peripheral issues, here is as good a source of information on most aspects of the topic as you could hope to find:
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=217783

But I think you need a JOIN for this job - It's been a while since I worked with EXCEL/ADODB, but you could give this a go:

```
SQLstr = "UPDATE [Location$] tLoc " & _
         "INNER JOIN [Current Location$] tCur ON tCur.Name = tLoc.Name " & _
         "SET tLoc.City = tCur.City"
```

**EDIT: connection across 2 files**

```
SQLstr = "UPDATE [Location$] IN 'D\Data\target.xls' tLoc " & _
         "INNER JOIN [Current Location$] tCur ON tCur.Name = tLoc.Name " & _
         "SET tLoc.City = tCur.City"
```

untested - might have to swap the table alias around

Comment: +1 That SQL string worked brilliantly! Thank you! I really appreciate the link too!

Comment: This may be inappropriate content for a comment and I may need to ask a new question... but what if the 'Current Location' sheet wasn't in the same workbook? Is there a way to reference another connection in the `SQLstr`, or is that outside the realm of ADO?

Comment: Thank you, Tim! I'll play around with that.

Comment: So I've spent several hours trying the example (and multiple variations of the example) you provided with no luck. And I can't find any examples online. Any chance you could take a look and see what's wrong? The error I get is `Syntax error in UPDATE statement.`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are missing some quotes '' which are required in an sql statement. For example

```
   "WHERE [Location$].[Name]=[Current Location$].[Name]" should be something like "WHERE    
    [Location$].[Name]= '" & [Current Location$].[Name] & "'".
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That syntax won't work for VBA. It assumes `[Current Location$].[Name]` is an object or variable, but it's not. Also, adding tick marks around `[Current Location$].[Name]` gives the same error.